# Error vincular páginas Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

se me cierra el programa de Android al intentar cambiar de página y no sé que tengo mal..

Adjunto programa

```
package com.example.eac1;
```

Imports..

```
public class EAC1 extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText texto; // Creamos la variable texto que utilizaremos en el editText.
    TextView NomFinal;// Nom que sortira quan ompli l'usuari.
    TextView Adreça1, Carrer1, CP1, Poblacio1, DadesP, Telefon1, Web1; // Creem variables de les dades a demanar
    TextView ValorCarrer, ValorCP, ValorP, ValorT, ValorW; // Creem variables de les dades a omplir
    TextView ButtonMasInvi, ButtonResetInvi, TextNomInvi; // Creem variables dels buttons y el TextNom a esborrar.
    TextView ButtonEnvia, ButtonLlap, ButtonX, ButtonTlf, ButtonUl; // Buttons nous.
    TextView telf;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_eac1);
        // Inicializamos el EditText, básicamente lo pasamos a la variable texto para poder utilizarlo.
        texto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TextNom);
        NomFinal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.NomCognoms);
        telf = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Valortelf);

    }

    // Ahora vamos hacer el TEXTVIEW. Este programa detectara si el texto esta vacío o no.
    public void TextAcceptat(View vista) {
        // primero pasamos el texto a String para poder analizarlo.
        String textoFin = texto.getText().toString();
        if (textoFin.isEmpty()) { // Si el texto esta vacío..
            Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Heu d'escriure quelcom!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast1.show();
        } else { // Sino el resto del programa
            // Primero modificamos el textView para que muestre  el nombre
            NomFinal.setText(textoFin); // Transformem el viewText en el text que ha introduït l'usuari
            // Empezamos hacer visibles el resto de cosas:
            Adreça1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Adreça);
            Adreça1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Carrer1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Carrer);
            Carrer1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            CP1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CodiPostal);
            CP1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Poblacio1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.PoblacioDadesPersonals);
          Asi con todos....
        }
    }

    // Métodes dels botons!
    // El botónX lo que hara será resetear el editText.
    public void ResetTextNom(View vista) { //creamos el método.
        // Modificamos el valor del editText a vacío.
        texto.setText(""); // cambia el text actual a nada.
        NomFinal.setText("Nom i cognoms"); // Posa el nom que hi era a l'inici.
    }

    public void PasarPagina(View vista) {
        //El que farem es que el boto Llapis cuan apretem pasi a una altre pàgina
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dades_personals);
    }

    public void TornarInici(View vista) {
        //El que farem es que al apretar la X tornarem al menú inicial.
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_eac1);
    }

    public void Trucar(View vista) {
        // primero pasamos el texto a String para poder analizarlo.
        String textoTelf = telf.getText().toString();
        if (textoTelf == "Valor no definit" || textoTelf.equalsIgnoreCase("Valor no definit") || textoTelf.isEmpty()) { // Si el texto esta vacío..
            Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "El camp ''Telefon'' està buït!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast1.show(); // en aquest cas mostrare sempre que hi estigui el valor no definit i empty podría fer apart
            // verificacions per veure si conté 9 números etc.. Si hem dona temps pulire aquestes coses.
        } else { // Funcion llamar.
            String textoTelfFinal = telf.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(textoTelfFinal));
            startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        }
```

El layout de este:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.eac1.EAC1"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Valortelf"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
       // Borro info que no es prescindible. />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ValorPoblacio"
        android:layout_width="121dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/NomCognoms"
        android:layout_width="186dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
       />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/TextNom"
        android:layout_width="295dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType=""
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textColor="@color/colorNegre"
        android:textColorLink="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.555"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"

        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,RtlHardcoded"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="341dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonX"
        android:layout_width="46dp"
        android:text="@string/buttonX"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/buttonMAS"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,UnknownId" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonMAS"
        android:layout_width="46dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:text="@string/buttonMAS"
        android:textColor="@color/colorMas"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,RtlHardcoded,UnknownId"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/NomCognoms"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:onClick="TextAcceptat" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Adreça"
        android:layout_width="156dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:text="@string/adreça"
        android:textColor="@color/colorNegre"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,RtlHardcoded"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/NomCognoms"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/DadesPersonals"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.466"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/ButtonLLAPIS"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Carrer"
        android:layout_width="52dp"
        android:layout_height="23dp"
        android:text="@string/carrer"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Adreça"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CodiPostal"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:text="@string/codi_postal"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/ValorCodiPostal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Carrer"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/PoblacioDadesPersonals"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="@string/poblacio"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/CodiPostal"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/DadesPersonals"
        android:layout_width="156dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:text="@string/dades_personals"
        android:textColor="@color/colorNegre"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/PoblacioDadesPersonals"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,RtlHardcoded,TextViewEdits"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Telefon"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/telefon"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/DadesPersonals"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Web"
        android:layout_width="51dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/página_web"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Telefon"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ValorCodiPostal"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:text="Valor no definit"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/ButtonLLAPIS"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ValorCarrer"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText,MissingConstraints,RtlHardcoded" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ValorCarrer"
        android:layout_width="129dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:text="Valor no definit"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.204"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/Carrer"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/ButtonLLAPIS"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Adreça"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText,MissingConstraints" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ValorWeb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="valor no definit"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/Web"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText,MissingConstraints"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/DadesPersonals" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonUll"
        android:layout_width="53dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_view"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ButtonEnvia"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.904"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/ValorWeb"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ButtonTelf"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.55"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonTelf"
        android:layout_width="53dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_call"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.898"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/DadesPersonals"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ButtonX"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
        android:onClick="Trucar"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonX"
        android:layout_width="53dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.692"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/ValorCodiPostal"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ButtonLLAPIS"
        android:onClick="TornarInici"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonLLAPIS"
        android:layout_width="53dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/TextNom"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
        android:onClick="PasarPagina"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonEnvia"
        android:layout_width="304dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/envia"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ValorWeb"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

He creado la página nueva:

```js
package com.example.eac1;

 public class DadesPersonals extends EAC1 {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dades_personals);
                      }

    public void BotonAceptar (View vista){
        Intent intent= new Intent (this, EAC1.class);
        startActivity(intent);
           }
    public void BotonCancelar (View vista){
        Intent intent= new Intent (this, EAC1.class);
        startActivity(intent);
            }
    }
```

El layout de este:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.eac1.DadesPersonals">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextWeb"
        android:layout_width="99dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType=""
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textColor="@color/colorNegre"

        android:textColorLink="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/WebDaDesPersonals"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,RtlHardcoded"
        android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ButtonCancel" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextTelf"
        android:layout_width="153dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType=""
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textColor="@color/colorNegre"
        android:textColorLink="@color/colorAccent"

        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,RtlHardcoded"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/EditTextWeb"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/EditTextPoblacio"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.222"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/TelefonDadesPersonals"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextPoblacio"
        android:layout_width="135dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType=""
        android:text="@string/name"

        android:textColor="@color/colorNegre"
        android:textColorLink="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.111"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/PoblacioDadesPersonals"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/EditTextCP"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,RtlHardcoded" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextCP"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType=""
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textColor="@color/colorNegre"

        android:textColorLink="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/CodiPostalDaDesPersonals"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/EditTextCarrer"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,RtlHardcoded" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextCarrer"
        android:layout_width="181dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType=""
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textColor="@color/colorNegre"

        android:textColorLink="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/CarrerDadesPersonals"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,RtlHardcoded" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CarrerDadesPersonals"
        android:layout_width="99dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:text="@string/carrerDadesPersonals"
        android:textColor="@color/colorNegre"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,RtlHardcoded"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/CodiPostalDaDesPersonals"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CodiPostalDaDesPersonals"
        android:layout_width="185dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:text="@string/CodiPostalDadesPersonals"
        android:textColor="@color/colorNegre"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,RtlHardcoded"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/PoblacioDadesPersonals"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/PoblacioDadesPersonals"
        android:layout_width="144dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="@string/PoblacioDadesPersonals"
        android:textColor="@color/colorNegre"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/TelefonDadesPersonals"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,RtlHardcoded"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TelefonDadesPersonals"
        android:layout_width="127dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="@string/TelefonDadesPersonals"
        android:textColor="@color/colorNegre"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/WebDaDesPersonals"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,RtlHardcoded"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/WebDaDesPersonals"
        android:layout_width="179dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="@string/WebDadesPersonals"
        android:textColor="@color/colorNegre"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,RtlHardcoded"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ButtonAcept" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonAcept"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:text="@string/BUTTONaccepta"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,RtlHardcoded"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="97dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/PoblacioDadesPersonals"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.978"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:onClick="BotonAceptar"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonCancel"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:text="@string/ButtonCancela"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="97dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.989"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/ButtonAcept"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:onClick="BotonCancelar"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.eac1">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".EAC1">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".DadesPersonals"></activity>
    </application>
```

Es decir el que tengo que enlazar es el boton Aceptar y Cancelar con EAC1.

He tenido que quitar algunas cosas para que pudiera ponerlo entero..

No sé que tengo mal.. :(

gracias!

Comment: Montse Mkd hace tiempo no te veía por aquí, recuerda que el uso del LogCat es indispensable en el desarrollo Android, agrega siempre el mensaje de error desplegado en el LogCat, de otra forma pueden ser infinidad de causas.

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys ^_^ El log Cat me dice que Error con el programa EAC1-S2.... Nada más de información. Es decir me funciona hasta Darle aceptar que me peta..

Comment: En tu LogCat revisa que tengas seleccionado tu dispositivo, el paquete de la aplicación y verbose.

Comment: Revisa el LogCat Agrega tu AndroidManifest.xml por favor Montse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los botones en tu layout estan llamando los métodos

```
android:onClick="BotonAceptar"
```

y
`android:onClick="BotonCancelar"`

Estos métodos se llaman en la Activity `DadesPersonals`  debes asegurar 2 cosas, primero que extienda de Activity (no de EAC1 ya que en realidad es la Activity que vas a cargar):

```
   //  public class DadesPersonals extends EAC1 {
  public class DadesPersonals extends Activity{

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_dades_personals);
                          }

        public void BotonAceptar (View vista){
            Intent intent= new Intent (this, EAC1.class);
            startActivity(intent);
               }
        public void BotonCancelar (View vista){
            Intent intent= new Intent (this, EAC1.class);
            startActivity(intent);
                }
        }
```

y segundo que esten registradas tus Activity dentro del AndroidManifest.xml:

```
       ...
       ...
       <activity android:name=".DadesPersonals"/>
  </application>
```

---

El error mostrado en el LogCat es:

> IllegalStateException: Could not find method BotonAceptar(View) in a
>   parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on
>   view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id
>   'ButtonAcept'

Indica que no puede encontrar el boton en el layout el método y esto se debe a que dentro de EAC1.java estas cambiando los layout usando `setContentView()`, si se cambia el layout, la Activity no encontrará el método.

```
public void PasarPagina(View vista) {
    //El que farem es que el boto Llapis cuan apretem pasi a una altre pàgina
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dades_personals);
}

public void TornarInici(View vista) {
    //El que farem es que al apretar la X tornarem al menú inicial.
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_eac1);
}
```

Si deseas aparecer y desaparecer elementos agrupalos dentro de un layout Linear, Relative, Constraint y mediante el id de este layout puedes hacerlo visible o invisible:

Comment: No me funciona con todo lo que me comentas.. T_T

Comment: de esta forma ahora el Aceptar no me hace nada, pero el Cancelar me da Error y me para la aplicación.

Comment: BotonAceptar  y BotonCancelar  hacen exactamente lo mismo

Comment: Pues no se... :S No hay nada raro en mi programa.. he copiado y pegado..

Comment: cambiaste  extends EAC1  a extends Activity?

Comment: si :( y sigue igual..

Comment: entra aquí https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66166/discusion-montse

Answer (score 1):

Copie los dos metodos de DadesPersonals a EAC1 tal cual estan.

```
 public void BotonAceptar (View vista){
        Intent intent= new Intent (this, EAC1.class);
       startActivity(intent);
 }
   public void BotonCancelar (View vista){
       Intent intent= new Intent (this, EAC1.class);
       startActivity(intent);
}
```

Deje ambos metodos en **DadesPersonals** vacios:

```
 public void BotonAceptar (View vista){
       // Intent intent= new Intent (this, EAC1.class);
       //startActivity(intent);
 }
   public void BotonCancelar (View vista){
       //Intent intent= new Intent (this, EAC1.class);
       //startActivity(intent);
}
```

De esta forma Ud. Hereda los métodos de EAC1. Así quedan vinculados.
Esto le soluciona el problema de los botones, pero no se si continua con el problema de pasar de pagina.